# Insertar datos, comparar y ejecutar (o no) actualizacion

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente `query` donde si no existe el dato en **`BBDD`**, me actualiza un campo en concreto, pero estoy interesado en evaluar antes si ese dato va a ser o no modificado:

```
 INSERT INTO `Product` (`id`,`link`,`price`,`description`) VALUES 
    ("1","product1","12.99","product1") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price = "12.99" ;
```

Tengo identificadas las siguientes causisticas:

- Si no existe el dato inserta la fila.
- Si existe el dato, evalúa la celda "**price**".
- Si dato a insertar en celda "**price**" es la misma, no hacer nada.
- Si dato a insertar en celda "**price**" es diferente, hacer el `update`.

Como adapto la `query` para detectar previamente si el valor **price** es el mismo o diferente para aplicar (o no) a posteriori el `update`?

gracias!

Comment: Tendrias que usar un trigger y de ahi agregar todo eso que mencionas

Comment: y no puedo poner un CASE para evaluar el dato y luego hacer (en caso de que sea diferente la comparación) el UPDATE?

Comment: Entonces, si es lo que queres, tendrias que hacer todo esto desde un procedimiento almacenado. Una sola instruccion sql no puede hacer todo eso.

Comment: Asi es, tal como menciona @gbianchi tendras que usar un sp para que por medio de variables obtengas los datos y con esos datos decidas que hacer

Comment: algun ejemplo con lo que tengo me podriais poner y lo adapto?